# Is there a way to 'pause' or partially consume a generator in Python, then resume consumption later where left off?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, generator

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001917/pause-python-generator). I am attempting to do [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler024/copy-from/1311767864) project Euler challenge on HackerRank. What it requires is that you are able to derive the *n*th permutation of a string "abcdefghijklm". There are 13! permutations.

I tried a simple solution where I used `for num, stry in zip(range(1, math.factorial(13)), itertools.permutations("abcdefghijklm"):`. That works, but it times out.

What would be really nice is to store each value in a `dict` as I go along, and do something like this:

```
import itertools
import math

strt = "abcdefghijklm"

dic = {}

perms_gen = itertools.permutations(strt)
idxs_gen = range(1, math.factorial(13))

curr_idx = 0

test_list = [1, 2, 5, 10]

def get_elems(n):
  for num, stry in zip(idxs_gen, perms_gen):
    print(num) # debug
    str_stry = "".join(stry)
    dic[num] = str_stry
    if num == n:
      return str_stry

for x in test_list:
  if curr_idx < x:
    print(get_elems(x))
  else:
    print(dic[x])
```

This doesn't work. I get this output instead:

```
1
abcdefghijklm
1
2
abcdefghijlkm
1
2
3
4
5
abcdefghikjml
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
abcdefghilmkj
```

As I was writing this question, I apparently found the answer... to be continued.

Comment: Which version of Python? In Python 2 zip returns a list. In Python 3, zip is an iterator like itertools.izip also map is like itertools.imap.

Comment: @DanD. Python 3. I thought that would be obvious from the code?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is "yes", you can pause and restart. How?

Unexpectedly (to me), apparently `zip()` restarts the zipped generators despite them being previously defined (maybe someone can tell me why that happens?). So, I added `main_gen = zip(idxs_gen, perms_gen)` and changed to `for num, stry in zip(idxs_gen, perms_gen):` to `for num, stry in main_gen:`. I then get this output, which, assuming the strings are correct, is exactly what I wanted:

```
1
abcdefghijklm
2
abcdefghijkml
3
4
5
abcdefghijmkl
6
7
8
9
10
abcdefghiklmj
```

After that change, the code looks like this:

```
import itertools
import math

strt = "abcdefghijklm"

dic = {}

perms_gen = itertools.permutations(strt)
idxs_gen = range(1, math.factorial(13))
main_gen = zip(idxs_gen, perms_gen)

curr_idx = 0

test_list = [1, 2, 5, 10]

def get_elems(n):
  for num, stry in main_gen:
    print(num)
    str_stry = "".join(stry)
    dic[num] = str_stry
    if num == n:
      return str_stry

for x in test_list:
  if curr_idx < x:
    print(get_elems(x))
  else:
    print(dic[x])
```

Comment: `zip` doesn't restart generators.

Comment: @user2357112 can you explain the output from that code then?

Answer (score 2):

Pausing is built-in functionality for generators. It's half the point of generators. However, `range` is **not a generator**. It's a lazy sequence type.

If you want an object where iterating over it again will resume where you last stopped, you want an iterator over the range object:

```
idsx_iter = iter(range(1, math.factorial(13)))
```

However, it would be simpler to save the `zip` iterator instead of two underlying iterators. Better yet, use `enumerate`:

```
indexed_permutations = enumerate(itertools.permutations(strt))
```

You've got a lot more things that don't make sense in your code, though, like `curr_idx`, which just stays at 0 forever, or your `range` bounds, which produce 13!-1 indices instead of 13! indices, and really, you should be using a more efficient algorithm. For example, one based on figuring out how many permutations you skip ahead by setting the next element to a specific character, and using that to directly compute each element of the permutation.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can consume part of an iterator `it`, just call `next(it)` to consume a single item. Or if you need to consume several at once you can write a function to consume `n` items from the iterator. In both cases you just need to take care that the iterator has not reached an end (`StopIteration` raised):

```py
def consume(iterator, n):
  for i in range(n):
    try:
      yield next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
      return
```

Which can then be used as such:

```py
>>> r = iter(range(5))
>>> print(list(consume(r, 3)))
[0, 1, 2]
>>> print(list(consume(r, 3)))
[3, 4]
```

In the end I don't see why you would need this for this particular problem, and as suggested there is a python function [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) that already iterate over all permutations for you.